# How can I throttle Netflix' bandwidth usage?

Tags: bandwidth, netflix, throttling

My ISP enforces a monthly bandwidth cap of 250GB.  Normally, that would be plenty, but Netflix is burning through my month's supply in about three weeks!  How can I force Netflix to use less bandwidth?  (Say, two or three bars of "quality", rather than 4+HD.)

We use Netflix primarily on a "slim" Xbox 360, but occasionally use it via the web site as well.  The tools I currently have at my disposal are a Netgear WNR1000v3 which runs our network and an older WGR614v8 which isn't currently hooked up.  Can I use these to reduce Netflix' consumption?  If not, what other (inexpensive) options do I have?

Comment: To the close-voter: I was expecting the answer to be router-related and therefore appropriate for this site.  But if there's another SE site where this would be more on-topic, I'd be happy to move it there. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sign into your Netflix account and click on `Account and Settings` then click on `Manage Video Quality` you can set it to use lower quality and therefore less bandwidth.

Comment: I was under the impression this setting only applied to in-browser player?

Comment: I thought it applied to all streaming, but I haven't found anything that says definitively either way. I'd give that a shot for now. If it doesn't work well enough, you can probably limit it via the router even more, maybe using QoS (if your router has it).

Comment: A brief test suggests that it doesn't affect the Xbox player.  :-/

Comment: Good to know. Sorry that didn't fix the issue. I guess you'll have to use another solution via router and QoS or something similar.

Comment: I stand corrected.  After a couple of weeks of watching our bandwidth usage, it seems to have made a *big* difference.  My initial test was based on video quality, which is only minimally affected.  (Yay!)

Comment: Glad it worked! I was kinda bummed out that it didn't seem to originally, so I'm glad you posted your results.